# How to Count List in 1 Cell on google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, split, count, sum, match

I want to count how many list in the cell. I have a table like this

[image]

And I don't know how to count that list so it can make out put like this

[image]

I'm sorry I'm not using the table to ask in here because I don't know how to use list on the table. You can Access the sheet here : [sheet2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S4jaRdWKryI3lHiN4RTQ14pWIuf7w22RoZ7oYJwY1q0/edit#gid=444721867)
Thanks!

Comment: Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** ([NOT as IMAGE](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)/Spreadsheet LINK) to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't [self contained](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: `I'm sorry I'm not using the table to ask in here because I don't know how to use list on the table.` Use ``</br>`` in between. Even if it doesn't work out or your don't know how to, editors can correct  your table based on supplementary image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A4, "[^\.]", )))
```

[image]